# Как получить данные из файла

Tags: python, парсер, анализ-данных

День добрый. Есть лог файл вида:

```
    revno: 4
    committer: user_Z
    timestamp: Fri 2012-03-16 14:01:31 +0700
    --
    revno: 3
    committer: user_Z
    timestamp: Fri 2012-03-16 13:52:26 +0700
    --
    revno: 2
    committer: user_Z
    timestamp: Fri 2012-03-16 13:39:19 +0700
    --
    revno: 1
    committer: user_Z
    timestamp: Fri 2012-03-16 12:56:22 +0700
```

Как можно получить количество коммитов, с разбивкой по годам.

Comment: Открыть, прочитать, проанализировать считанные данные. С чем именно проблема?

Comment: Я не знаю, как получить за какой либо год, всех коммитеров.

Comment: номера ревизий нужны? Комиттеры разные или всего один?

Comment: Нет. Только только коммитеры за год какой либо. Коммитеры разные.

Comment: Т.е. как должен выглядет результат? В 2012 году было 10 коммитов от юзера А и 15 от юзера Б, примерно так? Или в 2012 году было 25 коммитов, а в 2013 было 38. Или типа таблицы год, юзер, а на пересечении количество коммитов

Comment: Первое верно, год 2012, коммитов от юзера А столько, Юзер Б, столько.

Comment: а с чем именно у вас возникли затруднения?

Comment: Я не знаю как мне получить коммитеров и количество коммитов за определенный год.

Comment: @ItaRi, [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @ItaRi, [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В текущей формулировке вопрос скорее похож на тех. задание, т.к. включает в себя несколько вопросов/задач.

Отвечу на первый "подвопрос" - как спарсить данные в удобную для дальнейшего анализа структуру данных:

```
import re

with open(filename) as f:
    text = f.read()

data = re.findall(
    r"revno:\s*([^\r\n]*).*?committer:\s*(\w+).*?timestamp:\s*\w{3}\s+(\d{4})-", 
    text, 
    flags=re.DOTALL
)
```

результат:

```
In [195]: data
Out[195]: 
[('4', 'user_Z', '2012'),
 ('3', 'user_Z', '2012'),
 ('2', 'user_Z', '2012'),
 ('1', 'user_Z', '2012')]
```

Дальше нужно сгруппировать список кортежей по последнему и предпоследнему элементам и подсчитать количество записей в каждой группе. Перед группировкой список необходимо отсортировать по последнему и предпоследнему элементам кортежей.

Если возникнут вопросы/сложности с этим - откройте новый вопрос.

Comment: Большое спасибо.